# Limiting the numbers of rows returned with a COUNT(*) function in a WHERE clause as a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I searched a lot but I couldn´t find an explanation at all for my question.
Let´s say I have a database with 100 employees and I want to write a query, that tells me the three employees, which earn the most.
The query below works, but I have no idea why.

```
SELECT Name, salary 
FROM   employees e1
WHERE  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM employees
         WHERE salary > e1.salary )  <  3;
```

As far as I know, a `COUNT(*)` function only returns the total number of rows in a table. How can it be, that this query still works and returns me the top three earners. I can´t wrap my head around it and the more I think about it, the more I get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause of your query uses a *correlated subquery* that dynamically counts how many employees have a salary higher than the current employee. The correlation is implemented by condition `salary > e1.salary`, where `e1.salary` refers to the outer row (the *current* employee). Only employees whose salary is outscored by 2 or less other employees are returned; others are filtered out. This is you get the top 3.

I find that expressing this with a window function is easier to understand:

```
select name, salary
from (
    select
        name,
        salary,
        rank() over(order by salary desc) rn
    from employee
) t
where rn <= 3
```

Or, if you are running Oracle 12 or higher, you can use the `fetch` clause, which makes it straight forward:

```
select name, salary from employee order by salary fetch first 3 rows only;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and thank you for the other solution as well.
So to finally get this right now: `COUNT(*)` within a `SELECT` statements always returns me the number of colums in a table. But as soon as I run `COUNT(*)` as a subquery within a `WHERE` clause, it returns the whole row, back to the main query and then the output depends on what is in my main `SELECT` statement?
Is this correct? Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

First, here's how **the Rank() analytic function** will help with problems like this:

```
WITH rankings as (
   SELECT Name, salary, rank() OVER (order by salary desc) as theRank
   FROM employee
)
SELECT
  Name, Salary, theRank
FROM rankings
WHERE thRank <= 3;
```

First the `WITH` clause creates a virtual table called 'rankings' and uses the `rank()` and `OVER ()` analytic function to create an ordered column called theRank. Next the main `SELECT` statement simply queries out all the rows from that virtual table which match your criteria `theRank <= 3`.

**Why does yours work?** (without any more headache...) Your where clause includes a COUNT(*) but you are counting from employee where salary is greater than all the other salaries in e1 (which is also employee) Since there is no JOIN clause, this amounts to a Cartesian product between employee and e1, limited only by the > sign on salary.

Without too much frustration, think of this as the upper-half of a matrix where all salaries are both across the top and down the side.) The matrix is filled with True or False depending on whether the row salary is greater than the column salary. When you close off the parenthesis and ask for count(*) < 3 you are asking how many rows have only 2 False values (in other words who are the top **TWO** earners.)

I believe you should have to use <= 3 to get the top THREE earners. (but look into the Rank() and other Oracle analytic functions instead of writing queries with Cartesian products in them.) [Here's a decent reference for them.](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-rank/)

Comment: `< 3` is the correct condition in OP’s query, it means: there are maximum two higher salaries, which makes the query generate the top 3 earners (assuming no ties in third position).

Answer (score 1):

Since your table has a very small volume (100 records) you could take a simpler route and order your query by salaries descending, and limit the results to 3. Which will effectively show you the top 3 employees with higher salaries.

```
select
    Name,
    Salary
from
    employees
where
    rownum  <= 3
order by
    Salary desc
;
```

Comment: `limit` does not exist in Oracle.

Comment: @GMB You're correct. I've made a confusion with MySQL. I have edited my answer to the correct oracle keyword.